# Is it healthy to eat meat of an animal that died of an old age?

Tags: diet, food-poisoning

Given: *If an animal dies from disease or poisoning - eating that meat is not OK.*

If, however, an animal dies of old age - is eating that meat OK?

---

Not going into a topic of **animal exploitation**, **vegetarianism**, **veganism** - just want to know that if a cow lives - say 25 years - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle - *Breeding stock may be allowed a longer lifespan, occasionally living as long as 25 years.* - and dies of an old age - are there any medical and health considerations of consuming such meat?

---

Assumption - **death is recent**:

- occurs overnight in a monitored place
- it's the only cow in the whole village and villagers noticed

Comment: Why are comments disappearing without notice?

Comment: Owner of the comment has a right to remove it. AFAIR the comment was about *"age is not a reason of death"* - what I meant by ```dying of an old age``` was dying from natural reasons, because overall condition deteriorates, etc... (you get the gist)

Answer (score 1):

The only consequence is that meat from older animals is generally tougher. ([1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8586588)) To compensate, cooks usually use meat from older animals in soups, stews and other dishes that require long, slow cooking in liquid (braising). Braising breaks down connective tissue and tenderizes the meat. For example, older chickens are often referred to as stewing hens while younger birds are referred to as fryers, reflecting their best uses.